# NODEJS: Call async function outside of class

Tags: node.js, class, asynchronous

Basically, what I have is a file which contains a class **MyClass** which then contains some other functions within it which is being called by a separate file which works perfectly fine. However, I want to add an async function **outside** this class in the same file, and then call/execute it from one of the functions **inside** the class. It would look something like this:

```
async function myAsync(){

  //do stuff here

}

// Main class
class MyClass {

    firstFunction() {
       //call async function myAsync here
    }
}

// Exports class back to other file which runs it
module.exports = MyClass;
```

Comment: So whats the question? Just call the function.

Comment: @tkausl so would it work if I just placed a myAsync(); inside that firstFunction ?

Comment: @James: Yes, that's how functions are called. And async function simple returns a specific value, but it doesn't change how it's called.

Comment: @FelixKling I have just attempted to do that and it does nothing, nothing happens - its as if the firstFunction just skips over it...

Comment: Hard to say what the issue is without knowing what `myAsync` function does, how `firstFunction` is supposed to use it and what the overall result should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// file1
async function myAsync(){


}

 class MyClass {

    async firstFunction() {
        return await myAsync();
    }
}

module.exports = MyClass;



// file2

const my = new MyClass();

(async()=> {

  await my.firstFunction();
})()
```